# Do I have an error in my loop?

Tags: python, file, loops, try-except

I want to read an entire file "all_years.txt." (full of years/letters/words), line by line, and calculate if a year is a leap year. If so, I want to write that line into a different file that's empty called "leap_years.txt".

```
# calculation function
def leapYear(year):
    """ Calculates whether a year is or isn't a leap year. """
    year = int(year)
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

# main function
def main():
    try:
        file_1 = open("all_years.txt", "r") # open file
        lines = file_1.readlines()
        file_1.close()

        file_2 = open("leap_years.txt", "a") # open file

        for line in lines:
            if line.isdigit():
                if leapYear(line):
                    file_2.write(line)
        file_2.close()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
main()
```

This code does in fact, read the first file and prints to the other empty file, but it only prints "6464" which is the last line on the "all_years.txt" file. Why doe sit only print the last file??

It's supposed to ignore all of the letters in the file.
This is what the last 20 or so lines look on the "all_years.txt" file:

```
Lemming
2500
xyzw
2100
2101
2102
love
hate
3232
2054
2.71828
6504
6500
4242
1522
0.68
3333
666
325
1066
6464
```

Comment: I should say that every space between the text is a new line on the file... So it's basically a vertical version of what you see.

Comment: Use `line.strip().isdigit()` to remove the breakline `\n` or spaces in the line, maybe this is the problem

Comment: Because isdigit is only true if all characters in a string are digits. Spaces and line endings are not digits. You are also not really reading the original file line by line but that probably doesn't matter all that much unless the file gets big.

Comment: I have just about everything working correctly except for the fact that if there's letters after the year in the line, it won't print the year even if it's a leap year. How would I fix that?

Comment: # function
    def leapYear(year):
        year = int(year)
        return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 10 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

    # function
    def writeFile():
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip().isdigit():
                if leapYear(line):
                    file_2.write(line)

    # construct
    try:
        file_1 = open("all_years.txt", "r")
        lines = file_1.readlines()
        file_1.close()
    
        file_2 = open("leap_years.txt", "w")
        writeFile()
        file_2.close()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

Answer (score 1):

All of your lines except for the last line contain newlines, so `isdigit` returns false. Use `strip` on strings to remove whitespace from the ends. You can do it all in one place with a list comprehension:

`lines = [line.strip() for line in file_1.readlines()]`